# How to determine the number of a cube within a bigger cube? 

Tags: discrete-geometry

Hi all,

I have a cube, sized 39 x 13 x 8. I need to find out how many of them can fit in a cube of 100 x 100 x 100. I need to find the highest number possible.

Do you know of a way to do that without having to draw them, with trial and error?

Many thanks in advance

Septronic

Comment: I do not have a definite answer, and I am surely no expert on this topic. But I can say that similar problems are hard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem
In your case, a computer program might be the easiest way out.

Comment: Your latter cube is indeed a cube, but the first-mentioned "cube" is not. Such a rectangular body is called a *cuboid*.

Comment: Do you think trial and error will find the optimal packing?  I feel like I have to think "outside the box" to pack 5 unit squares in a 2.8x2.8 square.  Hopefully this sort of packing is not necessary for your problem.

Comment: @John : $\:$ I suspect that what the OP has is a _rectangular prism_, since a _cuboid_ can be more general.

Comment: FYI - I asked a follow-up question, and got an answer that might interest you: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131084/is-this-cube-packing-possible

Answer (score 4):

It might be hard to get an optimal packing, but it looks like [this paper](http://www.ime.usp.br/~egbirgin/publications/blm.pdf) can get you close.  Page 24 illustrates different instances of their algorithm's solution.  For example, this is how they pack 255 rectangles of size 137x95 into a 2530x1320 rectangle:

[image]

For more information, google "manufacturer's pallet loading problem."