# Is this cube packing possible?

Tags: packing-and-covering, discrete-geometry

I know how to pack $5$ unit squares in a square of side length $2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.  Is there an $\varepsilon>0$ such that there exists a packing of $9$ unit cubes in a cube of side length $3-\varepsilon$?

(Inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131047/how-to-determine-the-number-of-a-cube-within-a-bigger-cube).)

Comment: @Dustin, I see only a very weak analogy between the 2d and 3d situations described in your question. What am I missing?

Comment: When I asked the question, I was assuming the 9th cube had to be centered in the center of the $3−\varepsilon$ cube, but I couldn't tell if there was a way to rotate in a way that avoided the corner cubes as there clearly is in the 2-dimensional analog. 

Comment: If you center the $9$th cube, you can rotate it $45$ degrees about an axis parallel to an edge, and then when you project perpendicular to that edge you get the $2$-dimensional picture.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I saw the link in Ricky's answer. Considering I already understood the 2-dimensional setting, I definitely had a brain fart!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, since one can pack 10 unit cubes in a cube of side length $\:\:2+\left(\hspace{-0.023 in}\frac12\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.03 in}\sqrt2\right) \;\;$.

See https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cubincub .

Comment: Yeah, good point.  But 14 cubes??  Wow!

Comment: As far as I know, 15 might be possible. $\:$ 

Comment: The page illustrating these packings has moved to https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cubincub/